# add parameter to HTTPRequest header

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-3.0

I have form method declared as HTTP get, I have framework level restriction not to use POST request.

As I have a restriction in Apache that could not send more parameters as part of GET method in URL.

Is there any way to append parameters to `HTTPRequest` Header directly.

I don't have an alternative to put in session as target system don't want to make the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you shouldn't use JSP this way and I doubt that you can.

I suggest you choosing another framework which hasn't these restriction or simply creating separate servlet only to handle this form which will have all needed information hardcoded in class.